# Getting the decimal part of a number stored as string

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

The program I'm currently making requires me to store large floating-point numbers. I'm storing them as strings, which is working fine (of course I had to overload some operators that I needed) (I'm not allowed to use any multi-precision arithmetic library). Right now I'm looking for a way to get the decimal part of a number and also store it as a string. I thought about using stringstream and ignore, but that doesn't seem to be working. Is there something wrong in my code, as this doesn't do anything? Or is there some other method to achieve it (I was also thinking about a loop that would iterate through the stream until a dot, would that work?)

```
string toDecimal(string x)
{
string decimalValue;
stringstream x2(x);
x2 >> x;
x2.ignore(100, '.'); //it can have up to 100 places before the dot
decimalValue = x2.str();
cout << decimalValue << end;
return decimalValue;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get this:

```
 18432184831754814758755551223184764301982441
```

from this:

```
 18432184831754814758755551223184764301982441.4321432154
```

Comment: So you want to get substring from beginning up to the first dot? You can use  `std::string::find` to find the dot and then `std::string::substr` to get the substring from beginning to the dot position.

Comment: Do note typically the left side of the `.` is the whole part and to the left of the `.` is the decimal part.  For either of them though just use `find` and `erase` to remove the part you do not want.

Comment: @NathanOliver that doesn't sound *right* ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `c++`'s `std::string` class to accomplish this. The following code demonstrates how that could be implemented.

```
std::string toDecimal(std::string x)
{
    return s.substr(0, s.find("."));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using fancy `stringstream` or whatever, you can simply use:

```
char *x = "18432184831754814758755551223184764301982441.4321432154";
char *p = x;
while (*p != '.' && *p != 0)
    p++;
*p = 0;
// now x holds the string until the .
```

Comment: @AndreaGrillo can you please tell me why you think that `p++` instead of `*p=0` would do in this case? to me it seems like not doing anything and definitely not holding the string until the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Your method is completely valid(I understood that your method is to remove the fractional part of the string, but that's not what your code does). In therms of complexity, I don't think much can be added as you cannot magically discover the dot's position without making a linear sweep. That means your idea is good enough in terms of the algorithm itself. I think msrd0's answer will be more efficient in terms of execution as it uses a low level pure C implementation. But I think Emmanuel's is the best answer, as it is simpler and easier to maintain. But if you insist on having something similar to what you tried to do or **if you really need to use stringstream**, then I have this working version of your code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string toDecimal(std::string x){
    std::string decimalValue;
    std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
    std::stringstream x2(x);
    x2.ignore(100, '.'); 
    x2 >> decimalValue;
    std::reverse(decimalValue.begin(), decimalValue.end());
    std::cout << decimalValue << std::endl;
    return decimalValue;
}
```

Ps: This code assumes that you do have a dot inside the string.